# Convert none type to datetime using parser.parse

Tags: python, pyspark, python-datetime

I'm using the following function to parse string to date in `PySpark`

```
func = udf(lambda x: parser.parse(x), DateType())
```

My date format is:

```
"22-Jan-2021 00:00"
```

Althought this function does not work with `None` types, I have the following Spark data frame

```
date
----
"22-Jan-2021 00:00"
""
"10-Feb-2020 14:00"
```

When I apply my `func` to the `date` column I got an error on the second line of DF saying that it can't parse `NoneType`. Any tips to solve this problem using `PySpark` and the above `func` ?

An MVCE:

```
date = None
date_parsed = parser.parse(date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you could just use the `to_timestamp` function.

ex.

```
df.show()
+---+-----------------+
| id|             date|
+---+-----------------+
|  1|22-Jan-2021 00:00|
|  2|             null|
|  3|10-Feb-2020 14:00|
+---+-----------------+
```

You can simply use the following code to convert the string in the `date` column to a timestamp type.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions

df = df.withColumn("date", functions.to_timestamp("date", "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"))

df.show()
+---+-------------------+
| id|               date|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|2021-01-22 00:00:00|
|  2|               null|
|  3|2020-02-10 14:00:00|
+---+-------------------+
```

You can also verify that the conversion is done correctly with `df.schema`

```
print(df.schema)
StructType(List(StructField(id,StringType,true),StructField(date,TimestampType,true)))
```